# Why does direct carrier billing not work with certain carriers for Google Play in-app subscription purchases?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription, google-checkout

I have implemented [In-App Subscriptions with Google Play Billing API V2](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_subscriptions.html). Testing has been successful using Credit Card.

I do have issues with purchases made with Direct Carrier Billing though.

Here's what I have (testing with US-based carriers only):

- AT&T - works perfectly
- Verizon - works perfectly.
- Sprint - getting an error that "Direct Carrier Billing is not available (IAI).
- T-mobile - works perfectly as of 5/21/13.

What's interesting is that making purchases of **regular apps** using Carrier Billing seems to work, the problem only lies with purchasing **in-app subsriptions**.

Ruled out all configuration, etc issues, as the error occurs once inside Google Wallet GUI (after hitting the Accept button) and it does work 100% of the time for AT&T.

Anyone has any clue what's going on with DCB and IAB for subscriptions on T-mobile and Sprint?

**Update 04 20 2014**: It looks like the issue was on the carrier's side. [IAB v3](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)  seems to work as well. Your mileage may vary with other carriers.

**Update 05 27 2014**: It also looks like Google had added US Cellular to the list and it works well with IAB V3.